# Dynamic div id's with jQuery ajax php and javascript how to identify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, element

Simple question from a newbie to javascript / jQuery I cannot figure out. Maybe someone here can answer this.

Let's say I have a php script that loads thousands of rows and displays them one per line and each row has a userid associated with it.

Each row is displayed within a div andd each div has a unique id based on the userid.

So in my while loop I have

```
$id = "div${userid}";
```

then each line would be like

```
<div id='$id'>some info here </div>
```

My question is, if I were to trap for an onclick, normally I would

```
$('#div123').on('click', function() {
..
..
..
```

But since I don't know the names of the divs, how can I create at trap for an unknown?

```
$('#unknown').on('click', function() {
..
..
..
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

JT

Comment: I'd recommend setting an attribute on the line, such as `<div user-id="$id">info</div>` and then on the click access the attribute within the function with `$(this).attr("user-id")`. You could also just use the attribute `id` instead, but that has other properties in HTML. Then, for all divs, add a class to the user div such as `<div class="user-row" user-id="$id">info</div>` and capture click with `$(".user-row").click`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on

Answer (score 0):

You can find elements that start with a specific string. The code below will find any id that starts with `div`, for example `<div id="div123">`

```
$( "[id^='div']" )
```